# How to find out the memory area of an "optional" in swift?

Tags: swift, option-type, copy-on-write

I am studying CoW.
I understand that under the hood of an array and dictionary, the CoW works.

To check this, I looked at the memory area through the print.

```swift
var array1 = [1,2,3] 
array1.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (point) in
    print(point)      // 0x00006000006080e0
}
var array2 = array1 //  0x00006000006080e0
array2.append(4)   // 0x0000600002351ba0 <- changed
```

How can I see the memory area of an optional type? At the conference I'm watch, the author said that under the hood of the optional, the CoW also works and I want to check it out.

> **.withUnsafeBufferPointer** - for optional types does not work!

```swift
var optionalInt: Int?
optionalInt = 1                 // memory area?
var optionalInt2 = optionalInt // memory area?
optionalInt2 = 2              // memory area?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `withUnsafePointer(to:)`.

```
var optionalInt: Int?
print("optionalInt = \(optionalInt)")
withUnsafePointer(to: optionalInt, { pointer in
    print("optionalInt: \(pointer)")
})
optionalInt = 1
print("optionalInt = \(optionalInt)")
var optionalInt2 = optionalInt
print("optionalInt2 = \(optionalInt)")
withUnsafePointer(to: optionalInt2, { pointer in
    print("optionalInt2: \(pointer)")
})
optionalInt2 = 2
print("optionalInt2 = \(optionalInt)")
```

Output:

> optionalInt = nil
>
> optionalInt: 0x00007ffee58ede90
>
> optionalInt = Optional(1)
>
> optionalInt2 = Optional(1)
>
> optionalInt2: 0x00007ffee58ede28
>
> optionalInt2 = Optional(1)

Comment: I think I am really bad at documentation. How did you find it? Give advice for the future.

Comment: @errorka I knew about its existence, so didn't have to look for it. However, if you check the documentation of [`withUnsafePointer(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2998149-withunsafepointer), you'll find a whole [Manual Memory Management category](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management) under the documentation of the Swift Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

As David [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68654679/15692162) - the right decision. But you can run into a bug. And all your optionals will point to the same region in memory. This is what happened to me:

[image]

To avoid this, check like this:

```swift
func pointer(object: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return object
}

var optional1: Int?
var optional2: Int?

print( pointer(object: &optional1) ) // 0x0000000108f68090
print( pointer(object: &optional2) ) // 0x0000000108f680a0
```

Comment: You should never check memory in a playground. Playgrounds are not optimised and work quite differently from real Swift app/framework projects, so you should always use an actual Xcode project for debugging memory issues.